# Prove that anti-triangular block matrix with a Hurwitz block is also Hurwitz

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, lyapunov-functions, hurwitz-matrices

The closed-loop matrix of a dynamical system is an anti-triangular block matrix of the form

$$ A_\mathrm{cl} = \begin{bmatrix} A & BS \\ -\epsilon \left( G_u S \right)^\top {M} C & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

where the matrix $A$ is [Hurwitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_matrix), the matrix $G_u$ is full-column rank, the matrix $M$ is diagonal and positive definite ($M \succ 0$). Prove that the dynamical system is stable, i.e., that $A_\mathrm{cl}$ is [Hurwitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_matrix).

---

Can we say anything about the eigenvalues of $A_\mathrm{cl}$? Any theory or discussion would be helpful!

Comment: Is this by any chance related to the transmission zeros, which are defined by the generalized eigenvalue problem, which considers the following matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}A-\lambda\,I&B\\C&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: No, this the closed-loop matrix of a system which I am trying to prove to be stable ($A_\mathrm{cl}$ to be Hurwitz). Numerically, this matrix is indeed Hurwitz, however, I want to prove this analytically. I will edit the post to precisely reflect the particularity of this problem.

Comment: @yma26_math More details are needed. Please define all the matrices involved there and list all there properties; e.g. what is $B$, $S$, $C$, etc.